# Is there any npm package or any tool to save videos offline inside browser storage like either cache/indexedDB etc? I need to make an PWA

Tags: reactjs, google-chrome, video, progressive-web-apps

I need to make a PWA where mp4 video will be stored in browser storage, just like you can download videos in youtube website. And this website will be a PWA so user can watch their video while being offline. I could not find any packages, specially nothing for React.
The purpose of storing inside browser storage is to protect the video from sharing. Can you help me with any packages or codesandbox link?

I tried https://kinoweb.dev/ but this is totally vanilla js. And I can't store videos more than 100MB where my video can be upto 1GB.

Answer (score 0):

Shaka player actually provides this. Whoever is looking for this offline download thing please check this example. I have tested till 1GB file, it works fine.
[HTML example](https://github.com/shaka-project/shaka-player/blob/main/docs/tutorials/offline.md)

But one catch is your video has to be served from a mpd file from server.
You can use ffmpeg for converting mp4 to mpd.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33493740)